# why totalram of sysinfo is not equal to MemTotal in /proc/meminfo?

Tags: linux

We need to log the total RAM memory on our device which has Linux OS. I used totalram of sysinfo structure returned by sysinfo() to get the memory values. Today tester reported bug saying that the value is wrong as this value is different from the value reported in /proc/meminfo. I checked on the device and to my surprise, both are showing different values.

```
/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        1108976 kB

using sysinfo:
RAMTotalMemory : 1135591 kB
```

Can any one please let me know what is the difference between these 2 values.

Comment: Just a guess but I would think "RAMTotalMemoryFree"  is the amount of RAM that is free/currently unused, and the "MemTotal" is the total amount on the machine.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question now.

Comment: 1135591 * 1000 / 1024 = 1108976

Comment: @Lashane: can you please let me know why you did that calculation?

Comment: @kadina how many bytes in kilobyte?

Comment: @Lashane: 1 kilobyte = 1000 bytes. 1KB = 1024 bytes. But I didn't understand your calculation.

Comment: @kadina how many total bytes of memory device has? how many it is in kB and KB?

Comment: @Lashane Sorry. I didn't get.

Comment: @kadina then I cannot help :(

Comment: @Lashane: Thanks. I will try to figure out.

Comment: @Lashane: Thanks for trying to help me. I got it. While the file /proc/meminfo shows kilobytes (kB; 1 kB equals 1000 B), it is actually kibibytes (KiB; 1 KiB equals 1024 B). This imprecision in /proc/meminfo is known, but is not corrected due to legacy concerns - programs rely on /proc/meminfo to specify size with the "kB" string.